# JavaFX TableView delete issue

Tags: javafx, tableview

I'm having some issues with deleting datas from my TableView in JavaFX.
TabeView receives its data from a static ObservableList.

Problem: TableView shows 6 rows at a time. When there are for example 6 data-objects in my ObservableList and i delete 1 of them, the TableView seems to have some update-issues:

[Error](https://imageshack.com/f/pbEqN3aWp)

As you can see, the red highlighted row seems to be a copy of a still existing value in
my ObservableList. You cannot select this row cause there is of course no existing
value in ObservableList. This behavior keeps appearing after deleting some more values:

[enter link description here](http://imageshack.com/f/eys7rNowp)

All highlights "rows" are not selectable cause there is no corresponding value in my ObservableList. Only after deleting the last value / row in TableView it is refreshed and becomes empty.

My ObservableList ist static

```
public static ObservableList<ImageData> datas_all;
```

Deletion is pretty simple

```
@FXML
private TableView<ImageData> imageTable;

...

@FXML
private void handleDeleteImage()
{
    ImageData img_data = imageTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    Main.datas_all.remove(img_data);

    //if(Main.datas_flickr.contains(img_data))
    //  Main.datas_flickr.remove(img_data);

    //Main.db_adapter.deleteImage(new Integer[]{img_data.getKey()});

    //File del_file = new File(img_data.getPath());
    //del_file.delete();
}
```

TableView consists of two rows defined by

```
    @FXML
private TableColumn<ImageData,Image> columnImage;
@FXML
private TableColumn<ImageData,String> columnName;

...

public void redefineTableView()
{
    columnImage.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<ImageData, Image>, TableCell<ImageData, Image>>() 
    {
        @Override
        public TableCell<ImageData, Image> call(TableColumn<ImageData, Image> param) 
        {
            final ImageView imgView = new ImageView();
            imgView.setFitHeight(100);
            imgView.setFitWidth(100);

            TableCell<ImageData, Image> cell = new TableCell<ImageData, Image>() 
            {
                public void updateItem(Image image, boolean empty) 
                {
                    if(image != null)
                        imgView.setImage(image);
                }
            };
            cell.setGraphic(imgView);
            return cell;
        }
    });

    columnName.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<ImageData, String>, TableCell<ImageData, String>>() 
    {
        @Override
        public TableCell<ImageData, String> call(TableColumn<ImageData, String> param) 
        {
            TableCell<ImageData, String> cell = new TableCell<ImageData, String>() 
            {
                private Text text;

                public void updateItem(String string, boolean empty) 
                {
                    super.updateItem(string, empty);

                    if (!isEmpty()) 
                    {
                        text = new Text(string);
                        text.setWrappingWidth(170);
                        setGraphic(text);
                    }
                }
            };

            return cell;
        }
    });

    columnName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ImageData, String>("name"));
    columnImage.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ImageData, Image>("image"));

    imageTable.setItems(Main.datas_all);
}
```

I've googled this problem but nobody else seems to have it.
Please help me! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been asked before, but I can't find it now. The issue is that your `updateItem(...)` method does not properly handle the case where the image is null (or the cell is empty). This will be exactly the case when you delete an item from the table. You need:

```
        TableCell<ImageData, Image> cell = new TableCell<ImageData, Image>() 
        {
            public void updateItem(Image image, boolean empty) 
            {
                if(image == null) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    imgView.setImage(image);
                    setGraphic(imgView);
                }
            }
        };
        return cell;
```

and similarly for the other cell factory.

Comment: Thanks dude. It is quite obvious now :D. Btw it may be "else { imgView.setImage(image); setGraphic(imageView); }" and do the same in column columnName. =)